# Como uso el valor de un TextView.text o de un item seleccionado en un dropdown para usar en un Child para que active un nodo de Firebase en Android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, dropdownlist

Estoy hace dias intentando anidar dos dropdowns con valores dependientes de sus nodos.

El primer dropdown me da la lista de regiones (que tengo en firebase) y abajo otro que dependiendo de la region seleccionada, me dice las provincias que pertenecen a esa region.

El primer dropdown, me trae perfectamente los datos, pero cuando guardo la informacion de la region seleccionada en un TextView (no es la intencion de guardarlo ahi, pero es lo que parecio mas facil para ver si traia el valor bien)

El segundo dropdown intente sin exito lo siguiente:

```
    mDataProv!!.child("Italy").child(reglist.get(pos1).toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot)........

Otra que intente fue:

mDataProv!!.child("Italy").child(regioneSeleccionada.toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot)........

Otra mas que intente fue (que fue la unica que me agrego pathString):

mDataProv!!.child("Italy").child("$regioneSeleccionada").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot)........
```

Desde ya agradecere si alguien sabe como corregir lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Escribo por aca porque no me deja comentar.
Probaste con selectitem.tostring?

Comment: gracias por la respuesta @NicoX Lamento no haber leido este mensaje antes., me di por vencido y rehice todo de nuevo con otras cosas...